# How to test django's front-end javascripts

Tags: javascript, django, testing, backbone.js, bdd

I'm trying to test my *django* powered website's *backbone.js* front-end.

I found out that *karma.js* and *jasmine* are for those frontend testing, but it seems like they are just for **"front-end"**, which means they cannot test interactions between front-end *backbone* models and my *django* REST API server.

What I'm looking for is an testing framework that can test front-end javascripts in a BDD style (**including interactions between front-end and back-end**).

I know that there are a few tools for testing DOM, such as *selenium* or *lettuce*, etc. But what I want is to test my front-end **"javascript"**, not DOM, and that's why I tried out **karma.js** and **jasmine** at first.

Is there any testing framework that can test front-end with back-end network interactions? Or is there any way to tweak **karma.js** to work together nicely with django's development server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lettuce + Selenium + Django's LiveServerTestCase is your best option for System/Integration testing in a TDD enviroment. The LiveServerTestCase supports testing fixtures as well as handles the set up and tear down of a working test server.

karma and jasmine are great for low-level, unit testing (ie things that don't require a DB layer or middleware layer). You shouldn't need Django in order to test these calls, because each API request should have an expected/known API response that should be used as the input for your JS functions.